# How would you adapt a brownie recipe to a two-bite cupcake size?

Tags: baking, brownies, cupcakes

How would you adapt a brownie recipe to a two-bite cupcake size? 
Additional constraint, I usually bake with whole wheat flouer, and try to reduce butter in favor of apple-sauce, olive oil and coconut oil. Eggs are fine.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have to admit I'm still slightly on the confused side; those two-bite brownies are, essentially, brownies, just a different size and shape. Have you tried using your regular brownie recipe and baking the "dough" in small greased foil cups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just used the same mix and the same baking time, just using a mini muffin pan in place of a 9x9 or 9x13 pan. It worked quite well, although I suggest using the mini muffin liners in the pan, because cleaning all those individual spaces in the pan after brownie baking goes much smoother. I found that without the liners, the tiny brownies seemed to stick quite a bit, even in my good Pampered Chef pan.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of the cupcake tin you may have to increase or decrease the cooking times and temperature. My favorite "brownie disguised as a cupcake" recipe is from Paula Deen - http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/paula-deen/peanut-butter-brownie-cupcakes-recipe/index.html